# Microsoft iSCSI initiator- Automatically connect to another target if the first target suddenly become unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2016, iscsi

I am trying to configure 3 Virtual Machine, all are window server 2016. One as an initiator while 2 others act as targets. Is there a way to automatically connect to the other target when the first target suddenly become unavailable (without rebooting) through iSCSI initiator?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called MPIO: you connect to *all* targets and as long as there's one path working the storage stays up.

You need to install the *Multipath I/O* feature and set the storage to use MPIO in the *MPIO* control panel.

[edit] In MPIO you can configure the path strategy: least queue depth, round robin, only failover, ... Open Disk Management and edit the disk properties.

Comment: tks a lot. You saved me.